# AngularJS: create element dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How do I go about create an element in my controller? e.g. on a click event?

example controller:

```
function AddCtrl($scope){

    $scope.add = function(){
         // do stuff to create a new element?
    }


}
```

example view:

```
<div ng-controller="AddCtrl">

    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    // create <input type="text" ng-model="form.anotherField">

</div>
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical mistake coming from jQuery moving to Angular or any other MVC library. The way you should think is to let the view react to changes in the scope.

```
$scope.items = []
$scope.add = function(){
     $scope.items.push({});
}
```

In the view:

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="item.property">
```

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS is intended to follow MVC - so the controller creating an element in the view doesn't agree with the MVC behavior. The controller should not know about the view.

It sounds as if you want to have a control appear based on some conditional logic.  One approach would be to bind to the visibility of the element.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, your controllers should not be manipulating the DOM directly. Instead, you should describe the elements you need in your templates, and then control their display with directives, like ng-switch, ng-hide / ng-show, or ng-if, based on your *model*, ie, your data.

For example in your controller you might do something like:

```
$scope.showForm = false;
```

And then in your partial:

```
<div id="myForm" ng-show="showForm">
    <!-- Form goes here -->
</div>
```

By switching `$scope.showForm` between true and false, you will see your *myForm* div appear and disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display an element based on some condition or after the click, use ng-switch: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

If you want to add multiple elements, create a repeated list of items and add an item to your view-model on clicking the button:

```
$scope.yourlistofitems = [];
$scope.add = function() {
     $scope.yourlistofitems.push("newitemid");
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="item in yourlistofitems" ng-model="item.property">
```

Comment: I would like to create some new element in the view (non existing on the load), e.g. add another input field for some more data